# Break setTimeout function inside foreach loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to break the setTimeout function which is started on page load. So what I am doing here is, If I click on the button then I making flag value to true and setTimeout should break which isn't happening here. 
This setTimeout function is inside the for each loop. Below is my code.

```
                rData[0].dt.forEach(function(d, i) {
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        if(flag === "false"){
                            console.log(flag);
                            reserRadius(i); //here I am changing radius of circle
                        }else{
                            console.log(flag);
                            clearTimeout();
                            return;
                        }   

                    }, i * 2000);
                });
```

Comment: `clearTimeout` expects an id returned from `setTimeout`, but where you have it doesn't make sense, because by the time the function is evaluated the timeout is already completed and there is no reason to call `clearTimeout`

Comment: It is unclear what you exactly want your code to do. You cannot remove `timeout` inside itself, because when executed, it is already removed. It will be useful to post a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) snippet in your question.

Comment: I have animation code which is running inside this setTimeout function. I want this animation to stop if I hover over a particular region, so I am trying to stop it with the help of button.

Comment: @castis I have already tried assigning to a variable but still not able to break the loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of creating all timeouts in one go, only create them when needed. This way you don't have to clear any of them when you have determined to stop:

```
(function repeat(list, i) {
    if (i >= list.length) return; // nothing (more) to do 
    var d = list[i]; // do you need d at all??
    setTimeout(function() {
        if(flag === "false"){
            console.log(flag);
            reserRadius(i); //here I am changing radius of circle
            repeat(list, i+1); // schedule next timeout only now.
        }else{
            console.log(flag);
            // Don't schedule next timeout. This breaks the "loop".
        }   
    }, 2000); // trigger 2 seconds from now. Note: no multiplying anymore.
})(rData[0].dt, 0); // pass initial values: the array and index.
```

In your version of the code, you would have to keep the *id* values returned by all `setTimeout` calls, and then pass them all (or at the least the remaining ones) to `clearTimeout`, one by one. This would make your code quite cumbersome. I think the above is a more efficient approach.

Answer (score 0):

> setTimeout cannot be stopped from its callback itself. setTimeout
>   returns a timeoutId which can be passed to clearTimeout which in turn will
>   stop that particualr timer.

One way to stop all such timers is to create an array of timeoutIds and make changes as following.

```
var timerIds = [];
rData[0].dt.forEach(function(d, i) {
    timerIds.push(setTimeout(function(){
        if(flag === "false"){
            console.log(flag);
            reserRadius(i); //here I am changing radius of circle
        }
        else{
            console.log(flag);
        }
    }, i * 2000));
}); 

function stopTimeouts(){
    timerIds.forEach(function(id){
        clearTimeout(id);
    }
}
function codeThatMightChangeFlag(callback) {
    // do a bunch of stuff
    if (condition happens to change flag value) {
        // call the callback to notify other code
        stopTimeouts();
    }
}
```

Refer: [Clear array of setTimeout's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13033232/2681312) and [Javascript - wait until flag=true](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22125978/2681312)